# How to count a persentage of a painted area of the screen?

Tags: react-native

[My question in one picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/huSC3.png)

There is a screen in my project where you able to draw on the screen; the goal of the screen - to draw over full screen in time. It was pretty hard to get paint part to work. but now its even harder - i dont know how to count the percent of painted area of the screen and show the result on the screen, at the same time changing it while painting on the screen.

I believe the right way to do so - to initialize a "var" and somehow make it depend on the area painted... But i still dont get the right way to do smth like this.

My project consists of two parts - absolute and block section. I will attach the parts of the both sections, so you can see how the painting part is done and so counting part (not done).
The absolute part is (do not included css);

```
  type PropsType = {
  blocksCount: number;

  selectedIndexes: Array<number>;
  setSelectedIndexes: (newSelectedIndexes: Array<number>) => void;
};
const AbsoluteSection: React.FC<PropsType> = (props) => {
  const [counter, setCounter] = useState(60);
  const navigation = useNavigation();
  const percent = Math.round(
    (props.selectedIndexes.length / props.blocksCount) * 100,
  );

  counter > 0 && setTimeout(() => setCounter(counter - 1), 1000);

  const navigate = (isFail?: boolean) => {
    navigation.navigate('TestResultScreen', {
      title: 'Мультитач',
      isSuccess: isFail,
    });
    props.setSelectedIndexes([]);
    setCounter(60);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    counter <= 0 && navigate(true);
  }, [counter]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (props.selectedIndexes.length >= props.blocksCount) {
      navigate();
    }
  }, [props.selectedIndexes]);

  return (
    <View style={styles.absolute_wrap} pointerEvents={'none'}>
      <Text size={24} color={'#AAAAAA'} isCenterAlign>
        {props.selectedIndexes.length <= 0 &&
          'Починай замальовувати пальцем екран'}
      </Text>

      <View style={styles.pie_wrap}>
        <Pie
          radius={80}
          innerRadius={75}
          sections={[
            {
              percentage: percent,
              color: '#FFC107',
            },
          ]}
          backgroundColor="#ddd"
        />
        <View style={styles.gauge}>
          <Text style={styles.gaugeText} size={28}>
            {percent}%
          </Text>
        </View>
      </View>
      <Text size={28}>{counter} сек</Text>
    </View>
  );
};
```

The block part (more to painting) is:

```
type PropsType = {
  isSelected: boolean;
  onPress: () => void;
};
const BlockItem: React.FC<PropsType> = (props) => {
  return (
    <TouchableOpacity
      onPress={props.onPress}
      style={[
        styles.block,
        {
          height: '8%',
          width: '16.6%',
          backgroundColor: props.isSelected ? '#F6CE0E' : 'white',
        },
        ,
      ]}
    />
  );
};
```

and

```
type PropsType = {
  isSelected: boolean;
  onPress: () => void;
};
const BlockItem: React.FC<PropsType> = (props) => {
  return (
    <TouchableOpacity
      onPress={props.onPress}
      style={[
        styles.block,
        {
          height: '8%',
          width: '16.6%',
          backgroundColor: props.isSelected ? '#F6CE0E' : 'white',
        },
        ,
      ]}
    />
  );
};
```

I hope for best and i will appreciate help a lot, since i trying to solve this thingy for a quite some time now and its not getting any easier)